# Convert SCSS to CSS automatically on live server

Tags: html, css, sass

I am new to SCSS. I love using SASS for my local development, but when I publish a client’s website and need to make a change, it’s a pain to have to dig out the old project and set everything up so I can edit locally and then publish those changes on the production site.

Currently, I make changes in the SCSS file and then I go to online SCSS to CSS converter tool and convert SCSS to CSS and then put that CSS into CSS file.

Is there any way that if I make a change in the SCSS file in the server then it should directly update the CSS file?

Currently, I use HTML, CSS, SCSS, and Javascript

Thanks,

Comment: did u check `node-sass` in npm ?

Comment: `node-sass` has been deprecated **for years**. Use [`sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass).

Comment: Use an **npm script** to automatically watch the files and compile them to a single CSS file - https://pineco.de/the-simplest-sass-compile-setup

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Why not use a proper deployment process where the CI server builds and deploys the files? I doubt that you can install a whole pipeline on any server

Comment: "it’s a pain to have to dig out the old project and set everything up so I can edit locally" — Your real problem here is that whatever mechanisms you are using to store your projects and then get them ready for editing again is too much work and you should investigate ways to streamline the set up. If you're only using HTML, CSS, SCSS and JS then you should be in a position where getting a project up and running is a simple Git checkout, and then two commands to install all the dependancies and run the dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sass` package instead of VSCode Extensions like `Live SASS Compiler`.

**Why should not we use "**Live SASS Compiler**" VSCode extension?**

1. Live SASS Compiler extension is old and hasn't been updated for a while.
2. Some features like `@debug`, `@warn`, `@error` won't work, so if you are using it, you have to use the `sass` npm package for that.

**So, How to install the sass package?**

1. So simple, just run these commands.

```sh
npm install -g sass
```

2. And convert **SASS** to **CSS** automatically by running the below command on your terminal.

```sh
sass -w source/stylesheets/index.scss build/stylesheets/index.css
```

More information is available on the [sass docs here](https://sass-lang.com/install)

Answer (score 0):

Source - https://pineco.de/the-simplest-sass-compile-setup
By - *Adam Laki*

---

Make sure your project has a `package.json` file (*and you have Node installed on your machine*). Run `npm init` if you have Node but not `package.json` file, to initialize one.

#### Install [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) package:

```
npm install sass --save-dev
```

[Learn more about the package and its CLI](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass)

#### In the `package.json` file's `scripts` section, add these:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass-dev": "sass --watch --update --style=expanded assets/css",
    "sass-prod": "sass --no-source-map --style=compressed assets/css"
},
```

#### Run scripts:

```
npm run sass-dev
// or
npm run sass-prod
```

> What is a source map? A particular file that allows the browser to map back from the processed, concatenated files to the original ones. It is helpful because we can see the original file names when we debug the CSS in the developer tools.

The above is a very basic setup to compiling SCSS files and "watching" them for changes. Your server should have a pipeline or some sort of build system that it would be able to run this *npm command* in order to compile SCSS files, so theoretically you don't need to push your pre-compiled CSS files to the server, but it does it by itself.